# How do you modify a multiline statement on the Command Line in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

When you have produced a multi-line command statement in MySQL:

i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
test1 varchar(50)
test2 varchar(40)  <-- Assume cursor is here
```

Under the assumption that you are at the third line, is there any way to move up to the previous line to modify it?

I've tried going to the end of the line and hitting the left arrow, using the mark function (CTRL + M) and selecting the line, and nothing seems to be working.

Using Windows 10, MySQL Command Line Client.

Comment: there isn't away that i know of, but you can just end the statement with a semicolon. then hit the up arrow key to grab your previous lines and enter them again line by line

Comment: If you want a do-over (like @TinTran describes) but you want to be sure that the query in the previous lines doesn't run and do something unintended, you can end the line with `\c` (for "clear") instead.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL has the `\e` command, which lets you edit the current command in your favorite editor.  So if you have a typo on a previous line, you can type `\e<enter>` and the editor will open, and you can fix the typo.

```
mysql> how
    -> tables\e
... in your favorite text editor, fix the query ...
    -> \p
--------------
show tables;

--------------

    -> ;
+---------------+
| Tables_in_foo |
+---------------+
| bar           |
+---------------+
mysql>
```

Note that the fixed command *is* in the command buffer, but mysql doesn't re-print the buffer.  Use the `\p` command to see your edits.

I have also noticed that even if the edited command contains a semicolon, you'll still need to add one at the command line to make it run.

On Linux the editor-of-choice is specified by the `$EDITOR` environmental variable, maybe Windows has an equivalent.  Sorry I can't test on Windows right now.

---

For more such tricks, see the mysql reference: [4.5.1.2 mysql Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html).